# Ruby Básico Hashes Suma de values y Sacar Promedio

Tags: ruby, diccionarios

Estoy con un ejercicio de un curso inicial de Ruby. Me pide sacar la sumatoria total de unos valores de una clave del hash y luego el promedio. A simple vista, la suma de todos y la división por la cantidad. Pero ahí llego a mi problema ya que no encuentro que método usar para lograr la división para obtener el promedio:
Ejercicio

```
`gatos = [{edad: 3, peso: 12}, {edad: 4.5, peso: 16}, {edad: 2, peso: 13},# etc...]
```

Mi respuesta =

```
peso_promedio = gatos.map do|it|it[:peso]end.inject(0, :+)
```

Obviamente me falta el promedio.

¿Algún idea? El ejercicio me pide usar los siguientes métodos ->
map max inject (aquí no sé como vincular a max, aunque puede ser que no vaya).

Muchas gracias por leer, Juan.

Comment: El método para dividir es `Integer#/`, e.g.:  `gatos.map { |gato| gato[:peso] }.inject(:+) / gatos.size`. Sin embargo, utilizar `map` y luego `inject` es redundante, podrías ahorrarte un ciclo utilizando únicamente `inject`: `gatos.inject(0) { |sum, gato| sum += gato[:peso] } / gatos.size`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Gerry!! había hecho otras pruebas poniendo la "/" pero estaba mal armado, así que tampoco me daba. Tu ayuda fue muy útil!